# Amine and Amide reactions with ketone

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

Amines react with ketones whereas amides do not. Can anyone please explain why?

Answer (score 3):

Protonation of the carbonyl group of a ketone allow amines to react via nucleophilic addition. This is because the added proton pulls electrons further away from the reaction site, thereby allowing the lone-pairs from the amine to attack the carbonyl carbon.

In the case of an amide, the C=O beside the nitrogen causes electrons to be pulled away because of the positive charge of the carbon. This means that despite the possibility of having a protonated ketone, there will still not be a reaction because the nitrogen is not nucleophilic.